# React DnD - auto drag

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

Consider the case of a click button which renders a draggable component at the position of the mouse cursor. What if I would like to trigger the drag operation without a click on the element but programmatically? Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It can happen programmatically with `click()` the problem in our case was that the custom backend would not allow it.